# Excel VBA - How to compare two ranges at 1 to 1 level in For Loop?

Tags: excel, vba

This question is slightly different from the existing questions on this site listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574598/compare-two-ranges-vba), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453313/compare-two-ranges-in-excel-not-to-be-compared-linearly) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270693/fastest-way-to-check-if-two-ranges-are-equal-in-excel-vba).

I want to write a UDF in Excel VBA (and not use any existing VBA Functions) to loop thru two ranges simultaneously at same level (1 to 1) and check if the two values match.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9v0W.png)

```
Public Function compare(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Integer
Dim i
For Each cell In r1
     if cell.Value = 'value from r2 at same range level,  1 to 1 compare
        i = i + 1
     End If
Next cell
compare = i
End Function
```

In this UDF it takes in two ranges as input. Assume they are single column and equal rows for simplicity. Now using a `For Each cell in Range` loop I wish to compare the two ranges at same cell level. Is this possible?

Would I need to create a Nested For and in every inner For, skips those many cells to match the cells of Outer For?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to a numbered loop.

```
Public Function compare(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As long
    Dim i as long, r as long
    For r=1 to r1.cells.count
         if r1.cells(r).Value = r2.cells(r).Value Then
            i = i + 1
         End If
    Next r
    compare = i    
End Function
```

There may other benefits from variant arrays, resizing r2 to always be the same rows x columns as r1 and restricting r1 and r2 to the .UsedRange.

```
Public Function compare(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As long
    Dim i as long, r as long

    'restrict to .usedrange so full columns can be input
    set r1 = intersect(r1, r1.parent.usedrange)
    'make sure r2 is same dimensions as r1
    set r2 = r2.cells(1).resize(r1.rows.count, r1.columns.count)

    For r=1 to r1.cells.count
         if r1.cells(r).Value = r2.cells(r).Value Then
            i = i + 1
         End If
    Next r
    compare = i    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that @rajeev.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped for the answer. Learnt something new today!